# Need explanation of Insertion Node in AVL tree

Tags: tree, insert, avl-tree

Can anyone explain how each case in the switch in the function InsertNode below happen and how it work.

```
int InsertNode(AVLNODE*& tree, int x)
{
    int res;
    if (tree == NULL) {
        tree = CreateNode(x);
        if (tree == NULL) {
            return -1;
        }
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        if (tree->Key == x) {
            return 0;
        }
        else if (tree->Key > x) {
            res = InsertNode(tree->pLeft, x);
            if (res < 2) {
                return res;
            }
            switch (tree->bal) {
                case 0:
                    tree->bal = 1;
                    return 2;
                case 1:
                    LeftBalance(tree);
                    return 1;
                case 2:
                    tree->bal = 0;
                    return 1;
            }
        }
        else {
            res = InsertNode(tree->pRight, x);
            if (res < 2) {
                return res;
            }
            switch (tree->bal) {
            case 0:
                tree->bal = 2;
                return 2;
            case 1:
                tree->bal = 0;
                return 1;
            case 2:
                RightBalance(tree);
                return 1;
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I got confused since the most of implementation of avl tree on internet usually declare the struct of tree is :int height instead of int bal as my university did.
Also,AVLTree is a pointer to this struct:

```
struct AVLNODE
{
    int Key;
    int bal; // element refer to the node balance or not 
             // 0: balanced, 1: imbalance to the left, 2: imbalance to the right
    AVLNODE* pLeft;
    AVLNODE* pRight;
};
```

and here is function RightBalance and LeftBalance:

```
void LeftBalance(AVLNODE*& P) {
    switch (P->pLeft->bal) {
    case 1:
        RightRotate(P);
        P->bal = 0;
        P->pRight->bal = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        LeftRotate(P->pLeft);
        RightRotate(P);
        switch (P->bal) {
        case 0:
            P->pLeft->bal = 0;
            P->pRight->bal = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            P->pLeft->bal = 0;
            P->pRight->bal = 2;
            break;
        case 2:
            P->pLeft->bal = 1;
            P->pRight->bal = 0; break;
        }
        P->bal = 0;
        break;
    }
}

void RightBalance(AVLNODE*& P) {
    switch (P->pRight->bal) {
    case 1:
        RightRotate(P->pRight);
        LeftRotate(P);
        switch (P->bal) {
        case 0:
            P->pLeft->bal = 0;
            P->pRight->bal = 0;
            break;
        case 1:
            P->pLeft->bal = 1;
            P->pRight->bal = 0;
            break;
        case 2:
            P->pLeft->bal = 0;
            P->pRight->bal = 2; break;
        }
        P->bal = 0;
        break;
    case 2:
        LeftRotate(P);
        P->bal = 0;
        P->pLeft->bal = 0;
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is too broad. I suggest you read explanations given on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree) or other resources. On Wikipedia the explanation and provided pseudo code is based on balance factor (BF). If you have a *specific* question, then ask about that, but currently it is too broad.

Comment: The link was quite help.I just debug and got the point of it.thanks